# why ostream's put pointer is modified even if i did not use ostream object

Tags: c++

I have the below code in my program. IoFile.out has few lines.

```
    int main()
    {
     ifstream inFile("Iofile.out", ios::in|ios::out);
     ostream outStream(inFile.rdbuf());

     cout << "tellp outStream " << outStream.tellp() << endl;  //  tellp outStream 0
     cout << "tellg inFile " << inFile.tellg() << endl;        //  tellg inFile 0

     cout << inFile.rdbuf();  // Print whole file

     cout << "tellp outStream " << outStream.tellp() << endl;  //  tellp outStream 21
     cout << "tellg inFile " << inFile.tellg() << endl;        //  tellg inFile 21
     return 0;    
}
```

The outputs of tellp and tellg are as shown in the comments.
My query is when I write the file content to cout I expect only the read pointer(i.e. tellg) of the streambuf to move to end of the file. But in this case I see that put pointer of outStream is also moved to end of file. Why is this ? Why printing the file to cout causing the put pointer of outStream to change ?

Comment: You print the whole file, right?
You use a streambuffer pointer in the ostream constructer.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot open an `ifstream` for writing. If you want both read & write access, use `fstream`.

Answer (score 0):

You print the whole file, right?
You use a streambuffer pointer in the ostream constructor.
Then you print the data (this moves the pointer) (the ostream have a reference)
And get the pointer position (after you move it)
Your string have how many chars? (21?)
You moved the pointer when you printed the rdbuf().
I think its because inside it uses a arithmetic over its pointer

Comment: Aren't there two separate pointers ? one for read and one of write to the streambuf?

Comment: The ostream is a pointer, but you pass a pointer streambuf* sb, and both streambuf point to the same location